# Publishing C# application with VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, deployment, publish

I have an application written in C# using VisualStudio 2015 and I want to publish it (eg give an exe or installer to somebody to use it on its PC). From VisualStudio there is possibility to click "publish" in solution explorer. The result files are:

-Application files (File folder)

-project.application (Application manifest)

-setup.exe (Application)

As far as I know "manifest" file should be some metadata, but I can execute that file and it gives me an installer (the same as setup.exe). After installing it runs an application (just like setup.exe). It makes me confused - what exactly  project.application is? Can I delete it and use only setup.exe? What is the correct way of publishing an app? One last thing: why does the installer run installation on first execution and run an application on any other? I would expect to run installation any time (just like other software).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a ClickOnce application.  See the following link for more information:
[ClickOnce security and deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment)

In a nutshell:
The installer copies the files to the users AppData and then runs the application.
There are also other options such as checking for updates from a network location or web address.  Then when you run the application it checks for updates and uses the manifest to do an incremental update of the application files.